# twitter bootstrap modal fade scrolls page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Twitter Bootstrap Modal scrolling the page up on show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894570/twitter-bootstrap-modal-scrolling-the-page-up-on-show)

I am having an issue with the Twitter Bootstrap modal. Specifically, if I apply the class `fade` to get the modal to fade in and out everything works fine.

But I get this strange issue where the page scrolls up.

It doesn't always scroll all the way up, I *think* it is scrolling only while the modal fade animation is running.

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/ebepet/3#85

Comment: I am using Google Chrome 24.0.1290.1 dev on Ubuntu, so it could just be an issue with the dev version of google chrome...

Comment: Just downgraded to the stable version (22.0.1229.94) and the issue is still present.

Comment: Issue not present in Firefox 16.0.1 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Issue not present in Internet Explorer 9

Comment: Issue not present in Firefox 16.0.1 (Windows)

Comment: Issue present in Google Chrome 22.0.1229.94 (Windows)

Comment: Issue present in Safari on Ipad, looks like this is a webkit issue.

Comment: Ah, can you please post your analysis as an answer so others can see the solution easily?

Comment: I was sort of holding out in hopes that another reopen vote would come through on http://stackoverflow.com/q/12894570/570918, since it was up first.  It currently has 4 reopen votes.  It's also from a newer user, and I hate to see them dismissed so hastily.

Comment: Yeah, I gave it a re-open vote.